# ASP Classic Session Variable Not Always Getting Set

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic ASP site I'm maintaining and recently we wanted to do special rendering actions if the visitor was coming from one specific set of websites.  So in the page where those visitors have to come through to get to our site, I put a simple line setting a session variable:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/clsdbAccess.cs"-->
<%
    set db = new dbAccess
%>
<html>
    <head>
      ...
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           ...            
           </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <%
    Session("CAME_FROM_NEWSPAPER") = "your local newspaper"  
    ...
    %>
      ... html stuff ...
    </body>
 </html>
```

Then, in all the following pages, whenever I need to put up nav links, menus, etc., that we don't want to show to those visitors, I test for if that session variable is "" or not, then render accordingly.

My problem is that it seems to work great for me in development, then I get it out into Production and it works great sometimes, and other times it doesn't work at all.  Sometimes the session variable gets set, sometimes it doesn't. Everything else works great. But our client is seeing inconsistent results on pages rendered to their visitors and this is a problem.  I've tried logging on from different PC's and I confirm that I get different, and unpredictable, results.  The problem is I can't reproduce it at will, and I can't troubleshoot/trace Production.

For now I've solved this by just creating duplicate pages with the special rendering, and making sure those visitors go there. But this is a hack and will eventually be difficult to maintain.

Is there something special or inconsistent about session variables in Classic ASP?  Is there a better way to approach the problem?  TIA.

**Update**
I have discovered that the first time you visit the site through that page, the session variable does NOT get set.  The menus and everything (that are supposed to not appear in those cases) show up the first time through.  Then, if you go back and refresh the login page, go through it again to the very same page, this time it works, and thereafter.  Then I went and deleted out all my caching, cookies, etc. and hit the login page again, got to my page: Bam, menus (i.e. no session variable) again.  I created a page, "sessionvars.asp" where I display the contents of that var and sure enough, it's blank. At least now that I can reproduce the problem at will, I should be able to duplicate it on Dev and track it down.

Comment: One possibility is that since session variables are stored in the clients browser as cookies so depending on the clients cookie preferences your variable won't get stored

Comment: They are?? I thought they'd be stored on the server.  That was the reason I decided to go with a session variable instead of cookies explicitly. Geez. I hate this classic stuff.

Comment: @Mike: You've got the wrong end of that stick.  All Rob was saying is that the key that __identifies__ the session is sent to the client as a cookie.  The actual data for the session __is__ stored server-side.

Comment: Session variables are stored on the server, but the session *id* is stored on the client.  This is so the server can uniquely grab the right session object for the request.  If you inspect your cookies when viewing your site, you'll see one named ASPSESSIONIDxxxxxxx where "x" is random sequence.  Many platforms (asp, asp.net, php, etc.) handle sessions this way.

Comment: Yeah, I see that little cookie in Fiddler. Okay, so that's not my problem.  I can't get this thing to duplicate in my Dev environment. I tried disabling cookies from my site, clearing out the cache, clearing out the cookies, using "InPrivate" mode, what else is there?  I can make it happen from a remote server I can RDP onto and browse with; but having a heck of a time doing that here on my laptop.  Grrrrr.

Comment: Does it matter that the login panel is rendered in an iframe on someone else's site?  Since it's my page, coming from my server, I never thought so. But now I'm wondering if there might be some kind of scoping problem.

Comment: There is definitely a scoping problem. I added the value of the session var into a comment in the main login window, which is rendered in an iframe on a client's site. The value is correct there. Then by the time it gets to my site in a new window, the value is gone. I think I will have to pass it into my domain using a querystring.

Comment: Here is a link a friend sent me that gave me the idea about the iframe scope. It's a handy list of potential culprits: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-won-t-my-session-variables-stick.html

Comment: I passed the value out of the iFrame using a hidden field (I was using a POST not a GET so no querystring), then right away I stashed it into the session variable once it was on my site in the clear. Seems to work well.  Thanks, all, for the advice and support!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with a VPS server. You can't use a Web Garden with Session variables in classic ASP.

Go to IIS Manager - Web Applicattion Pool and Change the number of Worker Process to 1.

If you are in a shared hosting ask for this configuration or change to an Application Pool with ohly one worker.

More info:
http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/54826-asp-sessions-web-gardens

Regards

[www.imaginacolombia.com](http://www.imaginacolombia.com)

Comment: Reducing the number of worker processes will reduce your connection capacity on that server though. If you need multiple worker processes ("web garden"), you need DIY or 3rd party session management like that Bytes article suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple scenarios where this could happen:

The first basically echoes @RobV's comment, but the gist is ASP sessions rely on on cookies stored on the browser client.  So if the user comes from a client that has cookies turned off you won't be able to retrieve any session variables for that client.

Another scenario is that some user sessions might be timing out.   For example, lets say the user goes to the page that sets the session variable (and your session timeout is, say, 10 minutes).  Then they go out and get a coffee or get caught up in a conversation.  Then the user clicks on a link from your page 30 minutes later, and by that time the session is abandoned.  You could try upping the session timeout and seeing if that improves the situation.

One workaround would be -- instead of the session approach -- to check the the client's [referring url](http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art29156.asp) (HTTP_REFERRER), and see if it is one the url's you consider to be the "local newspaper".   This is arguably more work (and some browsers hide the referrer anyway), but might yield better results.  Heck, you could try a combination of both approaches: session and referrer.

Comment: The cookies thing is a real issue, as many people turn off cookies, don't they?  If so, then I either can't control this issue or I've got to come up with another way to persist the flag, perhaps through a hidden field (there's no Viewstate in classic, right?).  The REFERRER idea might be worth looking into, too.

Comment: @Mike: There is a big difference between persistent cookies and volatile cookies (aka session cookies).  Many people do block persistent cookies but only the most paranoid block session cookies.  If this was a cookie blocking issue it would never work it wouldn't sometimes work.